# Keyboard inside glove

Tags: switches, keyboard

I have an idea on keyboard inside a glove. You would wear a glove which would have little switches inside every finger. When tapping with the finger it would send the index of the finger to the computer/mobile.

My problem is I have only experience with software (programming), but none with hardware. Also I have little experience with electricity (or idk how to say it). I need to connect it using USB to the computer/mobile and then listen for these signals.

My professional sketch:
[Keyboard in glove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgzJH.png)

Can anybody tell me how to start with such a thing?

Comment: A site rule that quite often causes questions to be closed: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*

Comment: Your best approach might just be to find a hardware engineer to partner with.

Comment: I want to build it myself, that's why I'm asking where should I start.

Comment: You would need some electronics between the switches and the USB connector. You may use an USB input PCB.

Comment: You should start with the basics about circuit loops, which means the boring stuff not involving what you want to build at all.

Comment: You're aware that gloves that interface to computers are a done thing?  I'd suggest that you start by investigating what's already out there, and possibly even find a brand and buy a pair to play with and maybe disassemble.

Comment: disassemble a USB keyboard or a USB game pad ... take out the PCB ... attach small switches to the PCB

Comment: yea that is also a possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hardware beginners, the Arduino platform is a good place to start (cheap, simple to use, lots of on-line examples).  Use the general purpose I/O to read the state of micro switches and communicate their status via USB.